# How do I break apart scanned letters using Gimp or Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, typography

I'm trying to create a set of vector letters from lettering that I have scanned in. An example is shown here:

[image: Hand-drawn letters scanned using Gimp]

I scanned the letters in groups of 4 instead of the whole page, but doing the whole page might be faster if breaking the letters apart is faster.

In Inkscape, I've opened the scanned image and used the `Path > Trace Bitmap` tool. When I try to use Break Apart, I get a solid fill on the letter counters. I can delete those, but then I end up with two paths for each letter.

[image: Example of handdrawn letters traced in Inkscape]

Is there a a better way to do this? Help from professional typographers welcome... although I realize that most don't use Inkscape.

Comment: Note that if you want to make a typeface, you are better off using a font software from the beginning.

Comment: Before continuing the battle, check this: http://www.high-logic.com/font-generator/scanahand.html. It's the home page of High Logic's Scanahand. It has a form that can be filled by hand or in a photo editor. Input the filled form. The output = a font file, ready to install and use.

Comment: These are both great suggestions. But at the moment, I'd like to have a full set of vector objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the outline and the counter are now separate paths. The easiest solution is to select the outline and the counter of a given letter and use *Path → Combine* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>). This way, they will be part of a single path object like before breaking up and the counter will act as such.

Comment: Great help. I loved your article on Blackletter and re-tweeted it. Strange: I teach in a department of Physics & Computers Science and live near the Perimeter Institute for Theoretical Physics :)